# Gmarker custom icon not showing full size

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

We have manage to create markers with custom icon where we define first the icon for e.g.

```
var pIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('alertIcon/P.png',
                                         new google.maps.Size(15, 15));
```

Then we define the marker in this manner.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: point,
                            map: map,                          
                            icon: yIcon
                        });
```

The issue now the custom icon appear but just partial of it not the complete one as we had in V2 what could be issue here?

Comment: Did the `var pIcon...` line get cut off?

Comment: also should it be `icon: pIcon` instead of `icon: yIcon`

Comment: @What line are you saying about ?

Comment: @Alex I have tried both yIcon and pIcon both showing the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('alertIcon/P.png',
    // This might be where you're running into trouble, set
    // Size(w,h) to the dimensions of the image
    new google.maps.Size(72, 95),
    // This is the origin, probably want to keep it at 0,0
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // This is the anchor. For Point(x,y) x should be
    // half the image width and y should be the height
    new google.maps.Point(36, 95)
);
```

Comment: it appear in full size but skew away from the original point it suppose to be and why is it two new.google.Point()?

Comment: Ahh ya I should have explained, the first point is the origin. The second point is the anchor. So the Point(x,y) x should be half the width (in my case 36 = .5 x 72) and y should be the height.

Comment: I added some comments to the answer which might help as well

Comment: I dont this comment This is the anchor. For Point(x,y) x should be
    // half the image width and y should be the height?

Comment: Whats the size of the image? If it was 100x200 then it would be Point(50,200), if it was 20x50 it would be Point(10,50). It sets the anchor point (the part of the image that points to the specified location).

Comment: The original size I check is 32 by 32. Thank you but when I google I found MarkerImage have many other option in it?

Answer (score 2):

An icon for a Google maps marker just needs to be a string for the URL of the icon image. Creating a MarkerImage is probably causing the Google maps api to scale down the size of your custom icon.

```
    var pIcon = "alertIcon/P.png"
```

This is all you should need when defining your icon.

Comment: I did this var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: point,
          map: map,         
          icon: "alertIcon/P.png"
      }); also the same